# setVisibility hides nearby objects aswell

Tags: android

Im hiding a button from within a handler (This is after i have made it Visible in another state of the app). The handler receives a message from a running thread and then updates the GUI.

The problem is that nearby (not all) buttons and textviews are also dissappearing from the screen.. Im using Relative Layout.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget54"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Fold" 
    android:visibility="invisible"/ >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRaise"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnFold"
    android:text="Raise" 
    android:visibility="invisible"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnRaise"
    android:text="Call"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtFlopTurnRiver"
    android:layout_width="135dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text=" " />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnCall"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnCall"
    android:text="Chip amount:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtHand1"
    android:layout_width="73dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text=" " />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDeal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/deal_deck"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRiver"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnDeal"
    android:text="River"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtHand2"
    android:layout_width="73dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtHand1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnRaise"
    android:text=" " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtHand3"
    android:layout_width="73dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnRaise"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text=" " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtHand8"
    android:layout_width="73dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtHand1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnRiver"
    android:text=" " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtHand6"
    android:layout_width="73dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtFlopTurnRiver"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtHand8"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:text=" " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtHand4"
    android:layout_width="73dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtHand6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtHand6"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnRaise"
    android:text=" " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtHand5"
    android:layout_width="73dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtHand4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtHand1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:text=" " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtHand7"
    android:layout_width="73dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtHand3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtHand3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnRiver"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:text=" " />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtChipAmount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnCall"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtHand1"
    android:text="103360" />
```

Does anyone know what could be causing the problem?

```
btnFold = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFold);
btnFold.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: What do you mean by disappearing, are the near the edge and are being pushed off the screen? Simply making one object visible shouldn't make any other objects invisible or gone.

Comment: Are you putting any other elements right or left of your fold button in your xml code? Shoudln't be a problem but it might

Comment: Hi Sam sorry for being a bit unclear. The Button "btnFold" is visible at a certain moment in my app. I want to hide it again by setting View.Gone. Doing this makes a TextView above this Button and left of this Button Disappear aswell. Im going to try and change the screen size of the emulator to see if they pop up somewhere else instead.

Comment: Hi Hasslarn this is indeed the case. I editted the question to include the entire layout. Any idea why it might cause a problem? Also the Textview that disappear are txtChipAmount and txtHand2

Comment: Could you post your entire XML file? I think it might be because when you set a view to View.GONE and work with a relative layout that has objects set relative to the View that is now gone, wonky things happen (because you're setting stuff relative to a view that isn't in the layout anymore). If you want to hide it, setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE) or post more details about what you actually want to accomplish and I can try to help.

Comment: Aaimit thanks for your reply. It seems View.Gone doesnt take any space in the layout. View.Invisble does exactly what i want. It takes space in the layout while making the button invisble. Thanks my problem has been solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I see your full xml - when you set a `View` to `GONE`, views that are set relative to it (`layout_toLeftOf`, `layout_above`) are put in the top left (or wherever their other constraints put them, e.g. a view that is `toLeftOf` and aligned parent bottom will go to the bottom left of screen now (it has nothing to be `toLeftOf` and is on bottom). I'd recommend setting `View.INVISIBLE` if you just want to hide a `View`, not `View.GONE` unless you have a specific reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the button you want to hide with a

```
<LinearLayout 
 android:id="@+id/LLid" 
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
....
>

</LinearLayout>
```

And made all layout_toLeftOf to the LinearLayout(LLid)

After that you define a visibility:gone to your button, and show them with setVisibility(VIEW.VISIBLE)